# JS array recursion for unknown number of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have an Object with nested objects in JS and there's an Object with array that has the same name and can pop up multiple times with different values.
I just want to sum the length of each array always going one level deeper till this object is missing.

for example:

`0 : {id: 1, importantObject: {id: 1, {importantObject: {id: 1, importantObject:{...},}, somethingElse: 23}, something: 'test'}`

`1 : {id: 2, importantObject: {id: 24, {importantObject: {id: 55, importantObject:{...},}, somethingElse: 92}, something: 'test'}`

and so on..

I've tried to do the following:

```
const getCount = (a) => {
    let count = 0;
    a.map((b) => {
      if (b.importantObject) {
        count += b.importantObject.length;
        getCount(b.importantObject)
      }
    });
     return count;
  }
```

However, I don't get the correct count. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'll be helpful if you can share the exact input data.

Comment: Please do not use `.map()` for simple array iteration. Use `.forEach()` or a normal loop to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when doing recursion you must use recursive call return value

```
const getCount = (a) => {
  let count = 0;
  for (let b of a) {
    if (b.importantObject) {
      count += b.importantObject.length;
      count += getCount(b.importantObject); // here
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that I should also call recursively call the return value. Thanks!